# Robot position Rviz is jumping

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using **Indigo** on Ubuntu 14.04. I use MoveIT to control a robot arm (cyton gamma 1500) and visualize it in Rviz.
I have a camera mounted on the gripper of the arm, and I'm detecting a chess board in front of the arm.

My problem that the current state of the is switching between the initial state and the real current sate.
So, if I send  a `group.move()` or `group.execute(plan)` command, than in **RVIZ** the current and goal states are showed well, but with a high frequency it appears the initial state (upright) of the arm.

This is not only a simulation issue, because in the `tf` topic also can be detected. The relative position of the chessboard is showed in the two places as the figure shows:[image: image description]

The green object is the detected chessboard at the first time published its position, while the `TF` arrow and axes are showing the **"current"** position which is a view from  the initial position of the arm.[image: image description]
Here you can see a frame where the current state (green) and the initial position (gray) is showed. The real position of the hardware is the green one.

Why does the the inital position always show up while I plane and execute ?
Do I have to set something in a **MoveIt** launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215742/robot-position-rviz-is-jumping/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was found in the `move_group.launch` I had a state publisher which published the initial state of the robot in lack of the `fake_controller`.

**This should not be in the launch file:**

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom_combined base_footprint 100" /> 
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
 <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2015-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0